# Integrating camel with springfox

Tags: apache-camel, springfox

How can we integrate camel with springfox for swagger api generation? I'm not sure if it's possible. Currently we are using *camel-swagger-java* component, but is not flexible enough for our use case below. As per my understanding *springfox* expects the rest paths to be definedin spring controller

We're using basic authentication for our service, and the the paths are defined through XML, need the *securityDefinitions* in generated api. *camel-swagger-java* doesn't allow this to be configured, it seems.
This is how our current setup looks like

```
    <restConfiguration component="jetty" bindingMode="json" contextPath="/" port="8080" apiContextPath="/api-doc" host="0.0.0.0">
       <apiProperty key="api.title" value="Title"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <rest path="" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
       <description>xyz</description>
        <post uri="query" type="com.myRequest"  outType=com.myResponse">
            <description>abc</description>
            <to uri="direct-vm:someRoute"/>
        </post>
    </rest>
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you can tell more about what flexibility you need.

Comment: Added the details , thanks

Comment: Okay see this ticket about adding support for security details in the rest-dsl: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9751

Comment: thanks @Claus, but we need to wait till 2.20.0 release I guess. Is there any known alternative? Still wonder why isn't this feature there in the first place, as it seems to me as a common use case

Comment: There are only 24hours per day and people have a lot to work on as well - and a life to live. Many open source projects appreciate contributions. So step up to the plate yourself etc and contribute such functionality: http://camel.apache.org/contributing

Comment: sure, i'll give it a try